# how to detect and store the digits before and after of hitting an operator in a javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*This project must be the most common projects that everyone tries to do. I had already done it by following a tutorial on Udemy. But now I want to make a calculator using my own logic and own problem-solving strategies.*

Problem-: I have currently 2 problems in my calculator application.
1) Users can enter only 1 digit number for calculation. I want it to work for 10 digit numbers.
2)To make the buttons work.
I will try my best to make you understand this problem as it is a bit different.
for eg-:
user enters digit 12 
then he presses +
then he presses 16

expected output-:

12+16 addition occurs and 28 comes at the output.

Present problem-:
First of all the user can't even enter 12. he can enter only 1 digit at a time.
and further, when he presses addition, there are no functions that do the calculations **because I am thinking on how do I detect the user input before and after he presses any operators and then save it to some variables and perform operations as per the operators.**

my present code-:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Calculator</title>
     <style>
      
     input
    {
     height:100px;
     width:150px;
    
     border-radius:10px;
      border-style:none;
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
    
    }
    .abcde 
    /*for display purposes*/
    {
     background-color:blue;
     height:100px;
     width:608px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     color:white;
     font-size:100px;
    
    
    }
      
     </style>
    
     <h1>Basic calculator</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <script>
      // function clearfunc()
      // {
      //  document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="0";
      // }
      function show(id)
      {
     if(id=="zero")
     document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="0";
    
     if(id=="one")
     document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="1";
      
        if(id=="two")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="2";
     if(id=="plus")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="+";
     if(id=="three")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="3";
        if(id=="four")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="4";
     if(id=="five")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="5";
     if(id=="minus")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="-";
     if(id=="six")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="6";
     if(id=="seven")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="7";
     if(id=="eight")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="8";
     if(id=="mul")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="*";
     if(id=="nine")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="9";
     if(id=="clear")
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="";
    
     if(id=="divide")
     document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="/";
      
    
     if(id=="equal")
      
    document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="=";
     
    
      }
    
    
      
    
      
      // function show1()
      // {
      //  var a=document.getElementById("zero123").value;
      //  document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="0";
      // }
    
    
    
    
     </script>
    
    <div class="abcde" id="abcd">
     
    </div>
    
      <input type="button" value="0" id="zero" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="1" id="one" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="2" id="two" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="return show(this.id)"> <br>
      <input type="button" value="3" id="three" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="4" id="four" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="5" id="five" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="-" id="minus" onclick="return show(this.id)"> <br>
      <input type="button" value="6" id="six" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="7" id="seven" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="8" id="eight" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="*" id="mul" onclick="return show(this.id)"> <br>
      <input type="button" value="9" id="nine" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="C" id="clear" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="=" id="equal" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      
     
      <input type="button" value="&#247;" id="divide" onclick="return show(this.id)">
    
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: For starters, you should probably store the current display value in a variable first and append to the value as required, whenever a button is clicked. You don't need so many if conditions, since you can directly use the value attribute.

Comment: i could not get what you mean. can i get an example of it?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Users can enter only 1 digit number for calculation. I want it to work for 10 digit numbers.

You have to write logic that appends the existing value which is not done in your code, in your code it will always replace with new-value.

> 2)To make the buttons work. I will try my best to make you understand
>   this problem as it is a bit different. for eg-: user enters digit 12
>   then he presses + then he presses 16

this will not the only problem it might be possible user enters
`22+22+33+45` and then presses `=` for calculation

for each value and operator, you can not have variable so I have used `regex` here
which will prevent the user to enter an invalid expression and we will only perform calculation if the user enters `=` button

```
    <html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Calculator</title>
      <style>
         input
         {
         height:100px;
         width:150px;
         border-radius:10px;
         border-style:none;
         background-color:black;
         color:white;
         }
         .abcde 
         /*for display purposes*/
         {
         background-color:blue;
         height:100px;
         width:608px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         color:white;
         font-size:100px;
         }
      </style>
      <h1>Basic calculator</h1>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="abcde" id="abcd">
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="0" id="zero" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="1" id="one" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="2" id="two" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="return show(this.id)"> <br>
      <input type="button" value="3" id="three" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="4" id="four" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="5" id="five" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="-" id="minus" onclick="return show(this.id)"> <br>
      <input type="button" value="6" id="six" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="7" id="seven" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="8" id="eight" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="*" id="mul" onclick="return show(this.id)"> <br>
      <input type="button" value="9" id="nine" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="C" id="clear" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="=" id="equal" onclick="return show(this.id)">
      <input type="button" value="&#247;" id="divide" onclick="return show(this.id)">
   </body>
   <script>

      //1. when load add initial "0" in div
      document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="0";


      function show(id)
      {

          let existingValue = document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML

          if(existingValue ==="0") {
            // 2. in case of user enters "0", and "0" already exist then we make div as empty
              existingValue = ""
          }

          /*
            3. instead always setting value using following way, can store it in a variable than store it
            so it would more readable.

            document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="2"; // instead we store it like -> nextValue = "2"
            document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML="+"; // instead we store it like -> nextValue = "+"
          */
          let nextValue = "";


          if(id==="zero")
              nextValue="0";

          if(id==="one")
              nextValue="1";

          if(id==="two")
              nextValue="2";
          if(id==="plus")
              nextValue="+";
          if(id==="three")
              nextValue="3";
          if(id==="four")
              nextValue="4";
          if(id==="five")
              nextValue="5";
          if(id==="minus")
              nextValue="-";
          if(id==="six")
              nextValue="6";
          if(id==="seven")
              nextValue="7";
          if(id==="eight")
              nextValue="8";
          if(id==="mul")
              nextValue="*";
          if(id==="nine")
              nextValue="9";
          if(id==="clear")
          {
              existingValue = "";
              nextValue="";
          }


          if(id==="divide") 
              nextValue="/";

          if(id==="equal") { // 4. only perform calculation when user wants it so on "=" perform calculation

            /*
                // 5
                assume input is -> "11-22+33" 
                then existingValue = 11-22+33
                operators will have value like ["", "-", "+", ""]
                here, split is function in which i had given regex 
                [0-9]+ means it will be splited with any between 0 to 9 so we will only get operators like: +, -, * and /

                // 6
                operators.slice
                operators = ["", "-", "+", ""] we got
                we no need leading and trailing "" so remove it, then i have only [-, +]

                // 7 
                similar to operators i had splitted using operators to fetch values
                values = ["11", "22", "33"]

                // 8
                in a while i have performed a calculation using following logic:

                values = ["11", "22", "33"]
                operators = ["-", "+"]

                  result  = values[0] operator[0] values[1]
                // -11    =   11          -          22

                now, values first two value replace with result value
                values = [-11, 33]

                and remove the first operator.
                operator = [+]

                this process we continue till I have only one value in values array, that value will result, that's at


                // point: 9
                validate function:
                this function used to check what value should be allowed after specific char.

                reg = ^([0-9]+[+\-\*\/]?
                this regex return false in case of user enters multiple operators etc..
                wrong input: 99+88+++ // this won't allow and i returned false

            */

              let operators = existingValue.split(/[0-9]+/gm); // 5
              operators = operators.slice(1, operators.length - 1); // 6. removing leading and trailing space

              let values = existingValue.split(/[+\-\*\/]+/gm); // 7.

              while (values.length != 1) {  // 8
                  let twoValues = values.slice(0, 2); 
                  values = values.slice(2, values.length); // removing first two value as we are calculating those twoValues

                  let op = operators[0];
                  operators = operators.slice(1,operators.length); // removing first operator as we are calculating using that operator

                  let result = 0;
                  switch(op) {
                      case "+":
                          result = parseInt(twoValues[0]) + parseInt(twoValues[1]);
                          break;
                      case "-":
                          result = parseInt(twoValues[0]) - parseInt(twoValues[1]);
                          break;
                      case "*":
                          result = parseInt(twoValues[0]) * parseInt(twoValues[1]);
                          break;
                      case "/":
                          result = parseInt(parseInt(twoValues[0]) / parseInt(twoValues[1]));
                          break;

                  }
                  values.splice(0,0, result); // adding result value at position 0

              }
              existingValue = ""
              nextValue = values[0];
          }

          let finalValue = existingValue + nextValue;
          let isValidValue = validate(finalValue);
          if (isValidValue) { // only append value if its validated
              document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML = existingValue + nextValue;    
          }            
      }

      // this function which will validate on every button
      function validate(finalValue)  // 9
      {
      var regex = /^([0-9]+[+\-\*\/]?)*$/i;
      return regex.test(finalValue); // 
      }

   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: too complex for a beginner like me to understand. i am not sure whether i should try to learn your answer or try solving the problem with my own logic.

Comment: I had edited my answer by adding an explanation point, go though comment point to understand the logic, let me know if you need more explanation